# SQL Query to Count Daily Totals Skips Days

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-ce

This query counts the amount of bottles we produce over a month and groups them by day. If there are no bottles produces that day then it is skipped from the output instead of returning 0 bottles produced. How can I return with the day's timestamp if there are no bottles produced? I heard the calendar table has to be used for this.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,CAST(t_stamp AS DATE)), COUNT(bottles) AS 'Good Bottles'
FROM bottles
WHERE t_stamp
    BETWEEN "any date"
    AND "any date"
GROUP BY CAST(t_stamp AS DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(t_stamp AS DATE) ASC
```

Current Output:

```
Aug 12, 2019 12:00 am..................4302
Aug 13, 2019 12:00 am..................2302
Aug 17, 2019 12:00 am..................1302
Aug 18, 2019 12:00 am..................4302
```

Desired Output:

```
Aug 12, 2019 12:00 am..................4302
Aug 13, 2019 12:00 am..................2302
Aug 14, 2019 12:00 am..................0
Aug 15, 2019 12:00 am..................0
Aug 16, 2019 12:00 am..................0
Aug 17, 2019 12:00 am..................1302
Aug 18, 2019 12:00 am..................4302
```

Comment: You need a [Calendar](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/calendar-tables) [Table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/bones-of-sql-the-calendar-table). You can't count rows for a date in a table, when that date doesn't exist in your table.

Comment: Thank You! I will look into creating a calendar table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate the days.  A pretty simple method uses a recursive CTE:

```
WITH dates as (
      SELECT CONVERT(date, "any date1") as dte
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, dte)
      FROM dates
      WHERE dte < "any date2"
     )
SELECT d.dte, COUNT(bottles) AS GoodBottles
FROM dates d LEFT JOIN
     bottles b
     ON CAST(t_stamp as DATE) = d.dte
GROUP BY d.dte
ORDER BY d.dte ASC;
```

Notes:

- If you have a calendar or tally table, then use that instead.
- If the number of dates exceed 100, you need to add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`.
- `COUNT(bottles)` looks suspicious.  Do you really intend `SUM(bottles)`?
- Converting a column to a `date` and then to a `datetime` is also suspicious.  It is unclear why you would want a `datetime` for the first column.

Comment: Thank you for your help Gordon. Using that query was the only way I could get close to what I needed. The table I am querying contains the "weight" of the good bottle and a timestamp. I had to get the number of bottles per day using a table that contains only three columns. This is a very old system.